# Why doesn't my belkin usb 2.0 4-port ultra-mini hub work on windows xp?

Tags: windows-xp, usb

I just bought a [belkin usb hub](http://www.belkin.com/IWCatProductPage.process?&Product_Id=608514&subid=367680).  I am running a fully updated Windows XP.  When I plug in the device, it is not recognized.  The device manager says "Unknown Device".  The device properties say "There is no driver installed for this device."  If I remove the device from the device manager listing and "scan for new hardware" I get back to the same state.

*Edit*: Its red light is on, so it is getting power.

Why is it not working, and how do I fix it?

Comment: It sounds like the hub no longer works.  Its also possible your not using a USB 2.0 port.

Comment: It's brand new.  However, it might be broken.  Any way I can tell more detail about what's happening?  I could get another hub, but I wonder if it's just not reliable: http://www.amazon.com/review/RZ853FOYBJ6D9/ref=cm_cr_pr_perm?ie=UTF8&ASIN=B000Q8UAWY&nodeID=&tag=&linkCode=

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

1. [Belkin's support page](http://en-us-support.belkin.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/6939) to see if there is something you are missing for that USB hub.
2. Also try to reboot your PC/laptop, but keep the hub plugged in.
3. Double check your chipset driver and update it if you need to, along side with any other drivers the PC/laptop manufacturer.

Good luck!

Comment: I updated my BIOS (!!), and now it recognizes it.  Well done sir!

Comment: @dfrankow You are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Try uninstall your USB root hubs in your XP device manager. After uninstall reboot the PC and try again. The drivers should automitically re-install.

If that does not work, it might be the actual USB port on the PC, not all USB ports actually support USB hubs. Usually the USB ports on the back of teh machine supports USB hubs.

You can also try and see if the manufacturer of your PC/laptop has any

Comment: Thanks. I've uninstalled and rebooted several times. And, I am plugging it in to a port on the back of the machine. And, I've tried another port.

Comment: Try it on another PC if you just to ensure it is actually working. Try another USB device to see if that driver installs correctly. If no USB decide are working, then its most likely the OS and we can go from there.